# Allowing downpayment

Tags: commerce

Is the a way to allow downpayment for customer-preoders.
I can create a content type that allows customers to place orders(pre-order) but I wish they could commit a certain fee, like 30% of the original price.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Any specific module you are using for orders?

Comment: My suggestion is to create is completely using your custom module to create complete order and partial payment process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use commerce, you and try and incorporate modules like these into your workflow:
commerce_payment_split
commerce_partial_payment
commerce_installments

For ubercart, there is: uc_partialpayment

My advice will be to look at these modules and then decide if you need a customized module based on one of these.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of modules are available for managing inventory and orders. Like Ubercart, Commerce.

But according to your requirement it seems that you want a partial payment system.

The default modules available in drupal community will not be able to provide you such kind of feature.

My Suggestion is to create it completely using your custom module and manage the complete order and partial payment process system.

Hope this will help you.